# Adding 3rd party framework into Xcode 4 project

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I'm trying to add a custom 3rd party framework into my Xcode 4 project for a program I'm trying to write for Mac OSX. The framework is libircclient found here: http://www.ulduzsoft.com/libircclient/

I have opened the Xcode project that was in the project cocoa directory and compiled it. Then I tried to drag the IRCClient.framework from the Products into my Xcode application but when I try to compile it there (my app currently is empty, its a brand new project), I get the following error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @executable_path/../Frameworks/IRCClient.framework/Versions/A/IRCClient
  Referenced from: /Users/Ray/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/IRC-cokndyzxhwruxqevwngcznzijjcm/Build/Products/Debug/IRC.app/Contents/MacOS/IRC
  Reason: image not found
```

Am I adding the framework correctly? I also tried right clicking on the IRCClient.framework and copying the whole directory to my application then tried to add it in the build phases in my app. I get the same error. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

It seems you forgot one single step:
the 'copy files' build phase must be added to your target (Add buildphase)
Set the destination to 'Frameworks' and drop your framework. (I was unable to select it after clicking the add button)